# Unable to upload images to AWS through a rails App using carrierwave and fog by heroku

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I am getting  following errors on my Heroku logs:-

Excon::Errors::Forbidden (Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden)
2013-10-02T16:25:51.131316+00:00 app[web.1]:   response => #"\n`InvalidAccessKeyId`The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.5CA6A058BCE5D28AQ6grl4LPNO+F9YVtJZA7YIASYUFw4IpggAVlMJEzsdAhdwSWOTIB8K+VolEwyGYLS3_KEY", :headers=>{"x-amz-request-id"=>"5CA6A058BCE5D28A", "x-amz-id-2"=>"Q6grl4LPNO+F9YVtJZA7YIASYUFw4IpggAVlMJEzsdAhdwSWOTIB8K+VolEwyGYL", "Content-Type"=>"application/xml", "Transfer-Encoding"=>"chunked", "Date"=>"Wed, 02 Oct 2013 16:25:50 GMT", "Connection"=>"close", "Server"=>"AmazonS3"}, :status=>403, :remote_ip=>"176.32.100.200"}, @body="\n`InvalidAccessKeyId`The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.5CA6A058BCE5D28AQ6grl4LPNO+F9YVtJZA7YIASYUFw4IpggAVlMJEzsdAhdwSWOTIB8K+VolEwyGYL

I have checked the AWS key for at least a dozen times.
I have set up Heroku variables by using following:

```
heroku config:add S3_KEY=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX S3_SECRET=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

But I get the error as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your AWS access key is invalid. A couple things to double check:

- Do your access key, secret key and bucket all match what's in the AWS dashboard?
- Are you setting those variables correctly in your carrierwave initializer? You should be able to check by running the following from `heroku run rails console`:  `CarrierWave.configure { |config| puts config.fog_credentials; puts config.fog_directory }`.

If you double and triple check those and there really isn't anything wrong, then you may have a weird problem with your S3 account (can you access your S3 account with another S3 utility using the same credentials?), or there's something loony happening in your code.

Good luck!

Comment: I can upload images from my localhost with same keys and credentials but once I push the code to Heroku and try to upload the picture through the heroku app I face this problem.

Comment: Taavo,
When I run the command I get following output: {:provider=>"AWS", :aws_access_key_id=>"S3_KEY", :aws_secret_access_key=>"S3_SECRET"}
S3_BUCKET_NAME
=> nil

Comment: And by S3_KEY, S3_SECRET, and S3_BUCKET_NAME, you don't mean the literal strings, right? The output included your actual correct credentials, and you edited them out?

Comment: I have exactly copied and pasted the literal strings. Is it due to the reason that in my local machine I have set those variables in a file config/environment/app_environment_variables.rb? The reason I have done is to prevent adding aws credential to Github. For Heroku I did set the parameters using 
heroku config:add S3_KEY=XXXX S3_SECRET=XXXXX
heroku config:set S3_BUCKET=bucket_name

Comment: Yeah, sounds like somewhere in your application you're overwriting either the environment variables or the carrierwave configuration. Shouldn't be hard to figure out if you just search for the strings you found. The `||=` operator is your friend. Or, if you don't want to deal with this on your own, you can use [dotenv-rails](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv), making sure to restrict it to the development & test groups.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out using Taavo's suggestion. I used figaro gem where I did put AWS credentials into config/application.yml.

In addition, I also changed my carrierwave.rb file from:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|

  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider: "AWS",
    aws_access_key_id: "S3_KEY",
    aws_secret_access_key: "S3_SECRET",

  }
  config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads" 
  config.fog_directory = "S3_BUCKET_NAME"
  config.fog_public = false
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}
end
```

to

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|

  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider: "AWS",
    aws_access_key_id: ENV["S3_KEY"],
    aws_secret_access_key: ENV["S3_SECRET"],
    #region: 'Northern California'

  }
  config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads" 
  config.fog_directory = ENV["S3_BUCKET_NAME"]
  config.fog_public = false
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}
end
```

Then added following to Heroku:

```
$ heroku config:set S3_BUCKET_NAME=your_bucket_name
$ heroku config:set S3_KEY=your_access_key_id
$ heroku config:set S3_SECRET=your_secret_access_key
```

That did the work. Thanks Taavo for suggestions.